# How to find a bijection from [0,1] into (0,1)?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

I was given a question to find a bijection $f$ from $[0,1]$ into $(0,1)$.I have no idea of how to do this.Can any one please help me to solve this?

Comment: Did you search for any similar questions?

Comment: You've asked like *three* of the same questions. Can you please relax your pace?

Comment: The thing is im don't get how to solve these kind of sums for any given interval :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both uncountable.

To map $[0,1] \rightarrow (0,1)$, try mapping $0 \mapsto \frac12$, $\frac1n \mapsto \frac1{n+2}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, and use the identity everywhere else.